# Crashlytics forceCrash not working

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics

I'm setting up a new project with iOS 10, Xcode 8, using Swift.
After all the initial setup, I've setup Fabric & Crashlytics, as explained in their documentation. Everything perfect.

The problem is that I'm forcing a crash (as explained in the docs), but I'm not seeing it in the Dashboard.

I'm aware of the debugger, running without it, launching the app again afterwards so the report is sent; but still no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR my device was connected, unplugged it and it worked.

Eventhough in the docs it is stated that you should kill the app from xcode, launch from the simulator, then run again, I wasn't able to get it to work.

Eventually, in some old(?) documentation [here](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/test-crash.html) I found the key: `Note that if your device is plugged into your machine, the debugger can still get in the way.`

So, just unplug the device, and everything works as expected. Weird.